# getting state and time of jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer

I am trying to get the state and time of the Jwplayer but I get an "undefined" message when trying to see the result of both. I am using Jwplayer 5.7. Please if you can look at my code to see what I have done wrong, that would be awesome. Also my jquery.post() to the database does not fire anything (might be because i am not getting a state). In my console log under networking I cant see the file being called upon.

One final note, I am trying to send the message to the database in a post when the user clicks out of the browser, so far I have not been able to get that to work yet. I think I might be on the right path so please any further guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
    $sessionid = 9;
    $channelid = 2;
    $ipaddress = get_client_ip();

        function get_client_ip() {
         $ipaddress = '';
         if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) )
             $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
         else if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) 
             $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
         else if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']) )
             $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
         else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']) )
             $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
         else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']) )
             $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
         else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) )
             $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         else
             $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

         return $ipaddress; 
    }
    ?>
    <!Doctype>
    <HTML>
    <head>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Cll on slider.js here -->
    </head>
        <body>
            <!--<div class="side_banner"><img src="images/logo1.png"/></div>-->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="grid4 omega">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <img src="images/banner.png"/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="video_container"></div>
                        <div id="timer"></div>
                        <div id="state"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jwplayer.js"></script>   
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("video_container").setup({
                         'modes': [
                        {type: 'flash', src: 'includes/jwplayer/player.swf'},
                        {type: 'html5'}
                    ],
                        'height': 405,
                        'width': 720,
                        'autostretch':'false',
                        'wmode':'transparent',
                        'controls':false,
                        'autostart':false,
                        'file':'<?php echo json_encode($sessionid); ?>.flv',
                        'repeat':true,
                    });

                    var state = jwplayer("video_container").getState();
                    var time = jwplayer("video_container").getPosition();
                    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'The time is ' + time;
                    document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = 'The player is in a ' + state +' state';
                    if(state == "PAUSED"){
                        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'On pause, the time is ' + time;
                    }if(state == "IDLE"){
                        //try to push to database
                        try{
                            $.post(
                                'save_time.php',
                                {time:time,
                                ipaddress:<?php echo json_encode($ipaddress);?>,
                                channelid:<?php echo json_encode($channelid);?>,
                                sessionid:<?php echo json_encode($sessionid); ?>
                                },
                                function data(){
                                    alert(data);
                                    if(data == 'failed'){
                                        alert(failed);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }catch(err){}
                    }

                    //take care of the exit
                    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                        console.log('leeeeeeaaavvvving');
                        //alert('Are you sure you want to close out?');
                        var formData = {time:time, ipaddress:<?php echo json_encode($ipaddress); ?>, sessionid:<?php echo json_encode($sessionid); ?>, channelid: <?php echo json_encode($channelid); ?>};
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'save_time.php',
                            type:'POST',
                            data: formData,
                            async: false,
                            timeout: 2000,
                             success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                            {
                                //data - response from server
                                console.log(data);
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                            {
                                console.log('errrororrrrrrr');
                            }
                        });     
                    }

                </script>
                <!--<div class="bottom_buttons">
                    <div class="button left">Start Over</div>
                    <div class="button right">Continue</div>
                </div>-->
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to where this is running?

Comment: Ethan thanks for responding. I am running this on a local server. I can try to put it on my test server as soon as I am back on a computer then post a link

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer here is a link: http://www.nsixty.com/nSixty_tests/microsite_test.php

Comment: It looks like when I refresh, I get a console error that this is undefined - "$.ajax({"

Comment: Hmm in my chrome javascript console I can see 2 errors but it doesn't show what they are. Looking into that now.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Ok I commented out the $.ajax({ part but still nothing. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Also, I would update to 5.10 and check this documentation - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31164/javascript-api-reference, free jw5.10 is here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.10

Comment: Thanks @EthanJWPlayer. I figured out that it has to be performed in an onclick type of scenario. Is there any other way where I can get the time of the video without having to click a button?

Comment: You need to have the player at least playing to get the time of the video first.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out incase anyone else had the same issue. This is what I did below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jwplayer/jwplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//create the general variables
var videoid = <?php echo json_encode($videoid);?>;
var ipaddress = <?php echo json_encode($ipaddress); ?>;
var channelid = <?php echo json_encode($channelid); ?>;

jwplayer("video_container").setup({
     'modes': [
    {type: 'flash', src: 'includes/jwplayer/player.swf'},
    {type: 'html5'}
],
    'height': 405,
    'width': 720,
    'autostretch':'false',
    'wmode':'transparent',
    'controls':false,
    'autostart':false,
    'file':'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/nPripu9l-60830.mp4',
    'repeat':true,
    'events': {
        onPause :function(){
            time = jwplayer("video_container").getPosition();
            //get state
            browsercloser(time);
        },
        onBuffer: function(){
            time = jwplayer("video_container").getPosition();
            browsercloser(time);
        }, 
        onPlay :function(){
            time = jwplayer("video_container").getPosition();
            browsercloser(time);
        },
        onIdle: function(){
            time = jwplayer("video_container").getPosition();
            try{
                $.post("save_time.php",{time:time, ipaddress:ipaddress, videoid:videoid, channelid:channelid}, function(data){
                  if(data == 'good'){
                    alert('We are all good');
                  }else{
                    //
                    alert(failed);
                  }
                });
            }catch(err){}
        }
    }
});

function browsercloser(time){
    //take care of the exit incase it happens on play or any other setting
            window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                console.log('leeeeeeaaavvvving');
                //alert('Are you sure you want to close out?');
                var formData = {time:time, ipaddress:ipaddress, videoid:videoid, channelid:channelid};
                $.ajax({
                    url:'save_time.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    timeout: 2000,
                     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        //data - response from server
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        console.log('errrororrrrrrr');
                    }
                });     
            }
}

</script>
```

It works on Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera.